# Do I need the "the" in the following sentence: "Whenever I got depressed, (**the**) sounds seemed amplified"

Tags: articles, definite-article

> Whenever I got depressed, (**the**) sounds amplified themselves ten or
>   twenty times.

Why or why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes there's a need for **the**:

> I then lived near an underground tunnel, and even in my best moods I found  **sounds** of passing trains annoying. Whenever I got depressed, **the sounds** amplified themselves ten or twenty times.

Sometimes there's no need:

> I was admitted to a psychiatric hospital for wearing ear mufflers at all times and behaving strangely. The matter is, I was depressed then. Whenever I got depressed, **sounds** amplified themselves ten or twenty times.

In the first text, "**sounds**" are mentioned in the first sentence, so in the second sentence we're referring to definite "**sounds**".

In the second text, there's only one mention of "**sounds**". There is no prior mention, so no need for **the**. And from the context we understand that the author means "any sounds", that is, "**sounds**" in a generic sense.

---

Since the word "**sounds**" is not "modified" by phrases that could help the reader understand whether he/she knows these "**sounds**", we heavily rely on context in using or omitting **the** before it.